# "Will" vs "Maybe I will" and "I think I will"

Tags: adverbs, future-time

Almost every English grammar book I`ve studied claims that "Will" is used to talk about plans decided at the moment of speaking. Sentences like "I will help you" or "I'll wait for you" give a strong impression of spontaneity. My question is the following:

When modified with "Maybe" or "I think" , does "Will" convey the same meaning? Or perhaps it shifts the meaning into something that's more concidered and deliberate? Let me give you a few examples:

**"I think I'll watch a movie this evening"**

or

**"Maybe I'll read a book"**

Do those sentences sound like a plan made before or at the moment of speaking?

Comment: No, it does not have the same meaning. will can be intention, yes, And maybe just adds to the indeterminacy of the intention.

Comment: Those sentences sound fine. If, all of a sudden, I thought to read to watch a movie or read a book, I would say, "I think I'll watch a movie (or read a book)" or "Maybe I'll watch a movie now (or read the book now)" or "I think I'll do this now or that now (or maybe later)."

Comment: Both of these sentences are fine and mean that you have already made a plan but you’re not sure whether you are going to carry out that plan. It’s also worth noting that ‘I think’ carries a higher probability of you carrying out the plan than ‘maybe’. Many websites say that ‘maybe’ implies a weak probability of 50% or less. https://www.google.com.sg/amp/s/learningenglish.voanews.com/amp/2887387.html

Answer (score 0):

Plain *X will Y* is used to talk about X happening the future, where it's expected X to happen.  *I will X* is often used to communicate one's plans or intents.

This can be modified with other words.

*Maybe A B* means *A may or may not B*.  So, for example, *maybe I will go to the store* means *I may or may not go to the store.*

It's uncommittal, you would say *maybe* if you are not sure or don't want to say yes or no.

*I think A B* has several meanings:

- If A is not *I*, it means *I believe A B* - you are expressing something you believe is true but haven't necessarily verified.  *I think John is at the park* means you believe John is at the park, but you are leaving open the possibility you may be wrong or that the situation has changed.
- If A is *I*, it means the same as *maybe A B* but with a stronger emphasis on *may* versus *may not*.  *I think I will go to the park* means you are more likely than not to go to the park, but there is still a possibility you won't go to the park.

  - This is also used as part of an idiomatic expression communicate you want to do something instead of something else.  This often has a slight tone of sarcasm.

    - *Do you want to go to the park?*  *No, I think I will read a book instead*.

Yes, *I might X* is equivalent to *maybe I will X*.

*I may X* is often synonymous but can carry an implication that permission is needed for X.  *Might* implies that permission is not needed or is already obtained.